Setting New Word Document Created From Excel VBA to Landscape Orientation
I am attempting to export data from an Excel table to a new MSWord Document, two-columns per page, landscape orientation.
I am able to create the two columns in the doc, but the document that is not being set to landscape orientation.
Ignore code attempting to format the document as that is work in progress.
Sub generate_word_doc()

Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objSelection
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim row_count, col_count As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Roster")
ws.Activate
row_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown)))
col_count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlToRight)))

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Activate

With objDoc
    .PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
    .PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount NumColumns:=2
    .PageSetup.LeftMargin = 18
    .PageSetup.MirrorMargins = True

End With

Set RosterTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(objSelection.Range, row_count, col_count)

With RosterTable
    
    With .Borders
        .enable = True
        .outsidecolor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .insidecolor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        
    End With
    .Rows(1).shading.backgroundpatterncolor = RGB(221, 221, 221)

    For i = 0 To row_count
       
        For j = 1 To col_count
        .cell(i, j).Range.InsertAfter ws.Cells(i + 2, j + 2).Text
        Next j
    
    Next i

End With

End Sub


Since you're using
Dim objWord

rather than
Dim objWord As New Word.Application

for example, that means you're using Late Binding and can't use Word constants without declaring them too. Accordingly, you'll need to replace
.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape

with
.PageSetup.Orientation = 1 'wdOrientLandscape

Alternatively, if you want to retain the Word constants with Late Binding, you could add:
Const wdOrientLandscape = 1

to the top portion of your code.

That worked...or i should say the approach using the CONST did.  The other two dim objWord as New Word.Application and simply setting the orientation =1 did not (no idea why not!).  But the CONST approach did work.  Thank you !
